# Zxing ITF barcode not scanning in custom app

Tags: android, zxing, barcode-scanner

I am trying to use zxing barcode inside one of my app to scan barcodes. I have used intent to start the barcode scanner on a button cick.

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "PRODUCT_MODE");
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

What I have found is that most barcode can scan fine but when I try to scan the ITF (Interleaved 2 of 5) barcode within my app it doesnt work but if I just use the zxing barcode scanner it works fine.

Now I have been searching for a while and have read that I can use ALLOWED_LENGTH. I couldnt find much information as to how to pass in this information to the scanner. I tried the following but its not really making any difference.

```
**int[] item = new int []{6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13};**
**intent.putExtra("ALLOWED_LENGTHS", item);**
```

I added the two lines above to my code. Can someone please let me know what is the correct way to acheive this please.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution**

```
intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", Intents.Scan.ONE_D_MODE);
```

Note: You should probably use the provided intents, instead of hard-coding the extras string

**Explanation**

This has nothing to do with allowed lengths. ITF is not one of the PRODUCT_MODE formats

```
PRODUCT_FORMATS = EnumSet.of(BarcodeFormat.UPC_A,
                             BarcodeFormat.UPC_E,
                             BarcodeFormat.EAN_13,
                             BarcodeFormat.EAN_8,
                             BarcodeFormat.RSS_14,
                             BarcodeFormat.RSS_EXPANDED);
```

It is included in the list of 1D formats

```
ONE_D_FORMATS = EnumSet.of(BarcodeFormat.CODE_39,
                           BarcodeFormat.CODE_93,
                           BarcodeFormat.CODE_128,
                           BarcodeFormat.ITF,
                           BarcodeFormat.CODABAR);
ONE_D_FORMATS.addAll(PRODUCT_FORMATS);
```

changing your intent extra would enable ITF support, but might have other consequences (eg product search functionality)

Comment: Hi,

Sorry took so long to reply back. Thanks for your help. What I did at the end was to put the following line in the code

`intent.putExtra("SCAN_FORMATS", "PRODUCT_MODE,CODE_39,CODE_93,CODE_128,DATA_MATRIX,ITF");`


Which is working now but I will try out your solutions later. Thanks again for your help